# Callback CompressedImage /w image_transport

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic, compressedimage, compressed-image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to get the images of a kinect topic via image_transport. I added a Subscriber like this

```
image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
image_transport::TransportHints th("compressed");
image_transport::Subscriber img_sub = it.subscribe("/camera/rgb/image_raw", 1, savingImagesCb, ros::VoidPtr(), th);
```

my Callback:

```
void savingImagesCb(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& msg)
```

It produces the compilation error:

```
logger.cpp:50:118:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:118:11: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >’
       BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(f(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

I need the CompressedImage format for further processing, but image_transport won't allow this. How can I subscribe to a topic of this type (other than a normal Subscriber)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302709/callback-compressedimage-/w-image_transport/) by [count_dueki](https://answers.ros.org/users/30399/count_dueki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport) provides transparent transport of images in compressed formats. This transparency means that on the subscriber side in the callback, you receive a `sensor_msgs::Image` regardless of which transport has actually been used. That's a feature, because this way, the transport can be transparently exchanged, without any need for code modifications on the consumer side.

Things should hence work if you change your callback to

```
void savingImagesCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
```

If you actually want to receive the compressed image, using a plain subscriber on the compressed topic directly should work (e.g. subscriber to `/camera/image_raw/compressed` for instance).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [count_dueki](https://answers.ros.org/users/30399/count_dueki/) on 2018-09-12**:
Thank you for your quick answer (and sorry for my late comment!). I have to access the compressed Image directly (to save it with its format), so I will go for a standard Subscriber now.